# How to represent "For all elements other than i & j in a table"

Tags: pattern-matching

I have a function F, function of four other f functions, as shown below (1, 2, 3, 4 are indices here)

```
F = f[1]*f[2]*f[3]*f[4]
```

I want to create a table using this function such that for each (i, j)th element f[i], f[j] and other f elements are replaced by functions X, Y and Z respectively. Replacing f[i] and f[j] is easy as follows, but I am not able to figure out how to represent "indices other than i and j" in this function.

```
G = Table[F/.{f[i] -> X, f[j] -> Y}, {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 4}]
```

Will appreciate any help.
thanks

Comment: Are you meaning some conditions about $i$ and $j$ ?

Comment: `f[Except[i|j]]` ?

Comment: For example if I take the second element of table i = 1, j = 2. It should have f[1] -> X, f[2] -> Y and f[3] -> Z and f[4] -> Z. So, {1,2}th element of the table should be X*Y*Z*Z and so on. In the example above, I am giving the simplified form of my problem. Thanks

Comment: All the solutions suggested here working fine for problem I mentioned here, but not for my original problem.  Sorry, It seems I oversimplified my problem. so let me rephrase - To be precise, I want to replace f[m, k] with f[m-1, k], where m is an independent integer and k is 1-4 other than i & j. The suggestion like f[m, Except[ i | j ] ] ->  f[m-1, Except[ i | j ]] works fine on up to some extent as m is getting replaced by m-1, but then k instead of remaining k becomes "Except[ i | j ]". I am posting the problem again as well.

Answer (score 6):

It should be noted that it feels a bit counter-intuitive to use `Table` and `ReplaceAll` like that but since it is used in the question, this answer will go along similar lines as there is not much context to favor a different approach.

```
G/.f[_]->Z
```

The rule `f[_]->Z` will match all instances of `f[_]` in `G` where `_` is anything that is not already replaced by `ReplaceAll` in `Table` (as described in the question) .

The output is

```
{
 {X Z^3, X Y Z^2, X Y Z^2, X Y Z^2}, 
 {X Y Z^2, X Z^3, X Y Z^2, X Y Z^2}, 
 {X Y Z^2, X Y Z^2, X Z^3, X Y Z^2}, 
 {X Y Z^2, X Y Z^2, X Y Z^2, X Z^3}
}
```

Comment: Or one character shorter:  `G/._f->Z` :)     (+1)